# How to disable Firefox's addons Adblock Plus's Tab on Sifr text in Firefox

Tags: sifr

How to disable Firefox's addons Adblock Plus's Tab on sifr3-r436 text in Firefox

update:

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/461/3435716393.jpg](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/461/3435716393.jpg)

Comment: From a user's perspective? Or from the site coder's perspective?

Comment: site coder's perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Or if you do, Adblock will adapt. There's no real solution here.

ClickToFlash for Safari recognizes sIFR and has an option for always hiding or showing the sIFR text. That'd be something for Adblock to implement though.

Comment: isn't there a way to hide adblock tab using any javascript

Comment: @Jitendra: If there was, then Adblock would have to implement a work-around. This really isn't your concern: from the user's perspective, Adblock is doing what it's supposed to.